# Power Bi - Inactive Relationships Filtering

Tags: powerbi

I want to be able to graph how many orders were placed, how many parts were ordered and what the inventory levels were each month.

I got the first part down but cant filter out by part numbers since they're already linked to date. Any ideas on how this can be done or if its even possible? [image: Data Model Image]

Comment: Search for Power BI Role Playing Dimension, or watch Patrick explain the options here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BxaUXlx3K4&t=214s

Answer (score 0):

Switch the Summarizaion on ISOWeek to "Do Not Summarize".  See [Ways to aggregate your data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-aggregates?tabs=powerbi-desktop#ways-to-aggregate-your-data)